# Django Query to find number of rows with a certain value greater than zero, grouped by user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a dataset such that each user has an integer as a score for each date in a certain date range.

I want to find for each user, the number of days on which he/she had a greater than zero score - so, I want to `group by` user and `count` number of scores greater than zero for each user.

How do I write such a query in Django 1.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below is equivalent to a SELECT query grouping by user and counting the number of entries, for all objects where the score is greater than (gt) zero:

```
from django.db.models import Count

results = MyObject.objects.filter(score__gt=0).values('user').annotate(total=Count('user')).order_by('user')
```

Which unless I'm mistaken is what you're asking for?

Comment: For each user, I want to find - how many of his scores are greater than zero - not the number of users with at least one positive score.
So, probably the only change that must be made should be: `Count('score')`, is that correct?
This will give a mapping from User to No. of Positive Scores I guess.

Comment: @Rayu, sorry I'm still not clear. My answer groups the results by user, and the total is the number of scores that are greater than zero. The results will look something like the below. The count argument could be the pk here, it doesn't matter. It's just counting the number of results returned, grouped by each user.
 [{
    'user': 1, 
    'total': 3
},
{
    'user': 2, 
    'total': 7
},
{
    'user': 3, 
    'total': 1
}]

Comment: Ok, that's exactly what I wanted.
What I didn't know about was the `values()` function. That's my main learning here. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok, that's good news. The values() function in this instance are the attributes you're grouping by, so say you wanted a second field to group on, say by user and colour, then you would get [{
    'user': 1, 
    'colour': 'red',
    'total': 3
},
{
    'user': 1, 
    'colour': 'blue',
    'total': 1
},
{
    'user': 2, 
    'colour': 'red',
    'total': 7
},
{
    'user': 2, 
    'colour': 'blue',
    'total': 4
}]