# display '0' in html if QuerySet = [ ]

Tags: python, django

I am building a view a Django to render how many rows in a field have values greater than 0. So, the view that I am making needs to count the values greater than 0. 
[Django Query to find number of rows with a certain value greater than zero, grouped by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40529522/django-query-to-find-number-of-rows-with-a-certain-value-greater-than-zero-grou) has been extremely helpful, however I am stuck with the result. I can't find  a way to tell my view to display '0' on my html page when the querySet = [], and the count when the QuerySet has something in it.

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       count_orders = Item.objects.filter(en_cours_de_reception__gt=0).values('en_cours_de_reception').annotate(count_orders=Count('en_cours_de_reception'))

        if count_orders == 0:
            count_orders = '0'

return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {'count_orders' : count_orders  })
```

How can I get that done in a Django view so that I dont get "QuerySet =[ ] in my html. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it. Did you know about Django Templates? So, if you need to display variable that you successfully set  a value, just write next line in a `index.html`: `{{count_orders}}`

Comment: sorry I must have poorly expressed my self, I am asking how to display 0 rather than "querySet=[] in my html